# Mask video in A-Frame

Tags: video, aframe

I am evaluating the A-Frame framework and I am struggling with one task.

I need to mask a video. A static mask, say a feathered oval, would be fine.

My first idea was to simply include a webm video with an Alfa channel, but that video format doesn't play (with or without A-Frame) on iOS, so some other solution will be needed.
https://simpl.info/videoalpha/video/dancer1.webm

I found some reading on masking with three.js but cannot quite figure out how to take that first use case (static mask) to A-Frame:
http://blog.cjgammon.com/masking-5-glsl

I am also evaluating if it can be done with React VR.

Thank you for any insights!!

Answer (score 0):

The anwser should lie in materials, but since I have almost no knowledge of them I can only offer a really simple workaround, until someone posts a real solution.

- If Your background is a single color, You can just make a transparent image - mask, in the backgrounds color, which You could place in front of the video.
   If placed 0.001 in front of the video, it looks like part of the masked image/video.
- If Your background is complicated, I would make a black image mask, and feather both the inner circle and the outer one, so it wouldn't look pasted inside the scene.

I'm really hoping for a material solution, as we could learn something really useful.